# Angular2 Tutorial (Tour of Heroes): Cannot find module 'angular2-in-memory-web-api'

Tags: angular, import, angular-tour-of-heroes

I have followed the [Tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/). After changing `app/maint.ts` in the Http chapter I get the error when starting the app via command line:

> app/main.ts(5,51): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2-in-memory-web-api'.

(Visual Studio Code gives me the same error within main.ts - red wavy underlining.)

Here is my `systemjs.config.js`:

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function(global) {
  // map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var map = {
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs'
  };
  // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
  };
  var ngPackageNames = [
    'common',
    'compiler',
    'core',
    'http',
    'platform-browser',
    'platform-browser-dynamic',
    'router',
    'router-deprecated',
    'upgrade',
  ];
  // Add package entries for angular packages
  ngPackageNames.forEach(function(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  });
  var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  }
  System.config(config);
})(this);
```

Here is my `app/main.ts`:

```
// Imports for loading & configuring the in-memory web api
import { provide }    from '@angular/core';
import { XHRBackend } from '@angular/http';

import { InMemoryBackendService, SEED_DATA } from 'angular2-in-memory-web-api';
import { InMemoryDataService }               from './in-memory-data.service';

// The usual bootstrapping imports
import { bootstrap }      from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    provide(XHRBackend, { useClass: InMemoryBackendService }), // in-mem server
    provide(SEED_DATA,  { useClass: InMemoryDataService })     // in-mem server data
]);
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

For me the only solution was to upgrade `angular2-in-memory-web-api` to `0.0.10`.

In `package.json` set

```
'angular2-in-memory-web-api': '0.0.10'
```

in the dependecies block, and in `systemjs.config.js` set

```
'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
```

in the `packages` object.

Comment: That fixed the module error. After that I got 404 errors - I needed to specify `'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }` in the systemjs.config.js file (see answer by @GrantTaylor) .

Comment: If you use Windows command prompt, then CD to the node_modules folder, run "npm update angular2-in-memory-web-api". And then restart the light server.

Comment: Of particular note, if you are using angular-cli to develop your application, then you must add `'angular2-in-memory-web-api/**/*.+(js|js.map)'` to the `vendorNpmFiles` array in the angular-cli-build.js file. Aftewards, you must point your system-config map like so: `'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'vendor/angular2-in-memory-web-api'`. And then rerun `ng serve` (or `npm start`) so that the angular2-in-memory-web-api files end up in the dist/vendor folder.

Comment: If you're using the Angular 2 Eclipse plugin, the following line goes in package.json, in the `dependencies` section: `"angular-in-memory-web-api": "0.1.1"`. I had to run `npm install` from the project folder afterwards, though.

Comment: I am still facing this problem :( even after following the required steps

Comment: I don’t even have a systemjs.config.js file anywhere in my project. I’m using Angular4, though.

Comment: I configured angular CLI to use yarn, and running `yarn add angular-in-memory-web-api --save` worked out of the box.

Comment: Make sure that the new version of in-memory-web-api is angular-, not angular2-... https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-in-memory-web-api Also note the version dependencies between Angular and the in-memory-web-api, there have been recent breaking changes.. read the CHANGELOG

Answer (score 102):

As for projects created using current CLI Tools, it worked for me by installing

```
npm install angular-in-memory-web-api --save
```

and then performing import as

```
import { InMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api/in-memory-web-api.module';
```

> My package.json

```
> "dependencies": {
>     "@angular/common": "^2.4.0",
>     "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.0",
>     "@angular/core": "^2.4.0",
>     "@angular/forms": "^2.4.0",
>     "@angular/http": "^2.4.0",
>     "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.0",
>     "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.0",
>     "@angular/router": "^3.4.0",
>     "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.3.1",
>     "core-js": "^2.4.1",
>     "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
>     "zone.js": "^0.7.6"   },

>     "devDependencies": {
>     "@angular/cli": "1.0.0-rc.4",
>     "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.0",
>     "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
>     "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
>     "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
>     "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
>     "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
>     "karma": "~1.4.1",
>     "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
>     "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
>     "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
>     "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
>     "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
>     "protractor": "~5.1.0",
>     "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
>     "tslint": "~4.5.0",
>     "typescript": "~2.0.0"   }
```

Comment: Thanks, also I had to import InMemoryDbService as : import { InMemoryDbService } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api/in-memory-backend.service';

Comment: After running the `npm install` command, I got version 0.3.2. With that version, I could just `import { InMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';` as described in the tour.

Comment: As @comecme pointed out, after running `npm install`, `import { InMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api'` works.

Answer (score 21):

Here is what worked for me:

I noticed that the package.json had the following version:

"angular**2**-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.20"

Note the "**2**" in the name.

However when referencing InMemoryWebApiModule it was using 'angular-in-memory-web-api' without the 2 in the name.  So I added it and it resolved the issue:

import { InMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular2-in-memory-web-api';

**Note**:  I found this in notice section of https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api

> As of v.0.1.0, the npm package was renamed from
>   angular2-in-memory-web-api to its current name,
>   angular-in-memory-web-api. All versions after 0.0.21 are shipped under
>   this name. Be sure to update your package.json and import statements.

Answer (score 18):

## Angular 4 Changes

As of October 17, 2017, the tutorial fails to mention that `angular-in-memory-web-api` is not included in a standard CLI build, and must be installed separately. This can be easily done with `npm`:

`$ npm install angular-in-memory-web-api --save`

This automatically handles the necessary changes to `package.json`, so you don't need to make edits yourself.

### Points of confusion

This thread is quite confusing as the Angular CLI has changed significantly since this thread was started; a problem with many rapidly-evolving APIs.

- `angular-in-memory-web-api` has been renamed; it drops the **2** from angular**2** to simply `angular`
- The Angular CLI no longer uses SystemJS (replaced by Webpack), so `systemjs.config.js` no longer exists.
- `npm`'s `package.json` should not be edited directly; use the CLI.

### Solution

As of October 2017, the best fix is to simply install it yourself using `npm`, as I mentioned above:

`$ npm install angular-in-memory-web-api --save`

Good luck out there!

Comment: Also you may need to update the package.json file with zone.js to 0.8.4 then run npm update and then try the install above.

Comment: Am facing a new issue here Cannot find module './in-memory-data.service'.

Comment: @kannan - 1. Did you install `angular-in-memory-web-api` with `npm`? 2. Is there an entry for `angular-in-memory-web-api` in your `package.json`? 3. try killing and restarting the Angular CLI: `Ctrl+C` to kill; `ng serve` to restart). Sometimes the CLI acts weird (Ditto for the Angular plugin for VSCode)

Comment: @MasterofDucks Bro solved this yesterday the problem was i haven't created the file that is why. thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 15):

It works for me:

In package.json dependencies block set ( use "angular" instead of "angular2")

```
"angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.3.2",
```

Then run

```
 npm install
```

OR

simply just run (my preferable)

```
npm install angular-in-memory-web-api --save
```

Answer (score 14):

I'm currently doing the tutorial and had a similar problem. What seems to have fixed it for me is defining a main file for `'angular2-in-memory-web-api'` in the `packages` variable in `systemjs.config.js`:

```
'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
```

Before I added this, there was a 404 error logged for `/node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api/` where it seemed to be trying to load a JavaScript file. Now it loads `/node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api/index.js` and the other files in this module.

Comment: There currently appear to be several errors with the HTTP portion of the Tour of Heroes tutorial.

Comment: This doesn't help with my error (with the error in question).

Comment: I first had to update ´angular2-in-memory-web-api´ (see answer by @traneHead), and then apply this answer.

Comment: Thanks, solved my problem. I didn't need to bump up to 0.0.10 as others explain.

Answer (score 10):

This solved the 404 problem

From Angular in-memory-web-api Documentation

> Always import the InMemoryWebApiModule after the HttpModule to ensure that the XHRBackend provider of the InMemoryWebApiModule supersedes all others.

Module imports should have InMemoryWebApiModule listed after HttpModule

```
@NgModule({
imports:      [ BrowserModule,
              AppRoutingModule,
              FormsModule,
              HttpModule,
              InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService),
              ...
```

Comment: It's also crucial that it comes after importing routes like AppRoutingModule in the Angular2 demo. I had AppRoutingModule after InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService) and it breaks everything.

Answer (score 6):

From your root folder (the folder contain package.json), using:

```
npm install angular-in-memory-web-api –-save
```

Comment: worked for me using the new quick-start guide with Angular-cli

Comment: @OST Dude even am using angular-cli but am facing this error Cannot find module './in-memory-data.service'.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest solution I could think of was to install the package with npm and restart the server:

```
npm install angular-in-memory-web-api --save
```

I almost installed the **angular2-in-memory-web-api** package, but the [npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-in-memory-web-api) says:

> All versions after 0.0.21 are (or soon will be) shipped under
>   **angular-in-memory-web-api**.

**Note**: This solution worked for a project that was created with the CLI tools, which does not list the package as a dependency, and might not solve the problem for projects that were created with the Quickstart seed, which does list the package as a dependency.

Comment: My issue was that `ng serve` was still running while this was getting installed. Had to shut it down and restart.

Answer (score 4):

**I am using angular 4 and below solved my problem.**

> npm install angular-in-memory-web-api --save

Comment: hi even am using angular 4 i had done as you said but am facing a new issue here Cannot find module './in-memory-data.service'.

Answer (score 3):

This was a real stinker. Thanks to @traneHead, @toni and others, these steps worked for me.

1. Upgrade `angular2-in-memory-web-api` to `0.0.10`
2. Edit the packages variable property in `systemjs.config.js`:

`angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'core.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }`

Comment: This video may also be helpful: [Angular2 Tutorial - HTTP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L7xPwhwbcHE&list=PL55RiY5tL51olfU2IEqr455EYLkrhmh3n&index=14)

Answer (score 3):

I create my project using angular-cli and i set in package.json "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.2.4" in dependences block and then i run npm install.

Work for me :D

Comment: Any recommendations on what count be causing this issue? Or what they can configuration they could verify or change to eliminate the issue? Perhaps the contents of your "package.json" could help.

Answer (score 3):

For users who generated an empty project with angular cli 1.4.9 (Actual on October 2017) and then started follow the instructions step-by-step, just run the following command:

```
npm i angular-in-memory-web-api
```

Just that command, without anything additional.

Hope that saves someone's time

Answer (score 2):

If you are using angular cli, you would get this error.

Please add `'angular2-in-memory-web-api'` in the `const barrels` in the system-config.ts file as below:

```
 const barrels: string[] = [
  // Angular specific barrels.
  '@angular/core',
  '@angular/common',
  '@angular/compiler',
  '@angular/forms',
  '@angular/http',
  '@angular/router',
  '@angular/platform-browser',
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',

  // Thirdparty barrels.
  'rxjs',
  'angular2-in-memory-web-api',

  // App specific barrels.
  'app',
  'app/shared',
  /** @cli-barrel */
];
```

And add `'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'vendor/angular2-in-memory-web-api'` as below.

```
System.config({
  map: {
    '@angular': 'vendor/@angular',
    'rxjs': 'vendor/rxjs',
    'main': 'main.js',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'vendor/angular2-in-memory-web-api'
  },
  packages: cliSystemConfigPackages,

});
```

Rebuild using `npm start`.  This resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the typescript definitions:

```
sudo typings install --save file:./node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api/in-memory-backend.service.d.ts
```

... specifying the dependency name:

```
angular2-in-memory-web-api
```

Then add the entry point for "angular2-in-memory-web-api" in **/systemjs.config.js**

```
var packages = {
  ...
  'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'core.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
};
```

Comment: I installed the typings like you wrote. That changed the contents of the typings folder (added "\definitions\in-memory-backend.service\index.d.ts" to browser and main subfolders, and added reference in browser.d.ts and main.d.ts files). What do you mean by "specifying the dependency name"?.  I added the entry point as you specified. But my error still persists.

Comment: When you run "sudo typings install...", typings should ask you "What is the dependency name?" and then you can enter "angular2-in-memory-web-api".

Comment: My answer applied to angular2-in-memory-web-api v0.0.7 btw.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I changed in systemjs.config  :

```
'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
```

By this line :

```
'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'core.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing this line, as suggested above, worked for me in the Angular 2 Heroes Tutorial:

```
'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'core.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it copying `index.js` and `index.d.ts` to `core.js` and `core.d.ts`, that is, inside `node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api` folder. Go figure out.

Answer (score 0):

The main answer helped me:
change

```
'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
```

to

```
'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
```

Answer (score 0):

in app\main.ts simply modify:

```
import { InMemoryBackendService, SEED_DATA } from 'angular2-in-memory-web-api';
```

to:

```
import { InMemoryBackendService, SEED_DATA } from '../node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api';
```

then add the index.js parameter in

```
var packages = {
    'app': { main: 'main.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main:'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
};
```

in systemjs.config.js

it's work for me.

Answer (score 0):

If using angular cli to build your angular2 app, including the angular2-in-memory-web-api involves three steps:

1. add the api to the system-config.ts file (inside the src subdirectory) like below:

   ```
   /** Map relative paths to URLs. */
   const map: any = {
     'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'vendor/angular2-in-memory-web-api'
   };
   /** User packages configuration. */
   const packages: any = {
     'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
   };
   ```
2. Add

   ```
   angular2-in-memory-web-api/**/*.+(js|js.map)'
   ```

to the vendorNpmFiles array in the angular-cli-build.js file like ofShard mentioned;

3. Of course, add to the package.json as described by traneHead; for 
   2.0.0-rc.3 I use the version below:

   ```
   "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.13"
   ```

I find this [link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/3rd-party-libs) "Adding material2 to  your project" explains the process of adding third-party libraries quite clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Latest fix as of this date, is to

1. replace all instances of "angular2-in-memory-web-api" with "angular-in-memory-web-api".
2. Change package.json dependency version from `"angular-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.20"` to `"angular-in-memory-web-api": "0.1.0"` 
   and `"zone.js": "^0.6.23"` to `"zone.js": "^0.6.25"`
3. In systemjs.config.js, change the path for index.js. It should look like:
   `'angular-in-memory-web-api': {
   main: 'index.js',
   defaultExtension: 'js'
   }`

Answer (score 0):

As of latest (currently 0.1.14), this is what's stated in the [`CHANGELOG`](https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

> In `systemjs.config.js` you should change the mapping to:
>
> ```
> 'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'
> ```
>
> **then delete from `packages`:**
>
> ```
> 'angular-in-memory-web-api': {        
>    main: './index.js',     
>    defaultExtension: 'js'      
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because I was importing `InMemoryWebApiModule` from `angular2-in-memory-web-api` I removed the 2. Actually I had two entries in my package.json file; one was `angular2-in-memory-web-api` and the second was`angular-in-memory-web-api`. Using `angular-in-memory-web-api` solved the problem for me. So your import should be like this:

```js
import { InMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
...
@NgModule({

imports: [
InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService)
]
})
```

Using cli-angular you need not to change anything regarding `system.config.js`.

Answer (score 0):

For me just doing an install from angular-tour-of-heroes directory works for me

C:\nodejs\angular-tour-of-heroes>npm install angular-in-memory-web-api --save

Answer (score 0):

The Best way is to install it using NPM e.g

npm install git+https://github.com/itryan/in-memory-web-api/ --save

it will add required reference

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem. I just [downloaded the entire example](https://angular.io/generated/zips/toh-pt6/toh-pt6.zip) near the end of part 7 (last part) of the tutorial and ran it. It worked.

Of course, you need to install and compile everything first.

```
> npm install
> npm start
```

I also changed 'app-root' to 'my-app' in app.component.ts.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { InMemoryBackendService, SEED_DATA } from 'angular2-in-memory-web-api';
import { InMemoryDataService }               from './in-memory-data.service';
```

The `InMemoryDataService` class doesn't come under any API. We need to create a service class and then import that service class into app.module.ts file.

Answer (score -1):

Toni,
You need to add the typings for Angular2-in-memory-web-api.

Add them in your TS file.

```
/// reference path=”./../node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api/typings/browser.d.ts”
```