# Error 404 angular2-in-memory-web-api

Tags: typescript, angular, in-memory-database

I would like to use `angular2-in-memory-web-api` but I get these errors :

```
GET http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api/index.js.map 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api/in-memory-backend.service.js.map 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api/http-status-codes.js.map 404 (Not Found)
```

In the angular2-in-memory-web-api folder I have these files with extension .js and .d.ts but not .js.map

I read this [Angular2 Tutorial (Tour of Heroes): Cannot find module 'angular2-in-memory-web-api'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37377529/angular2-tutorial-tour-of-heroes-cannot-find-module-angular2-in-memory-web-a) and test every solutions but it still doesn't work for me.

Here my code:

boot.ts :

```
// Imports for loading & configuring the in-memory web api
 import { provide }    from '@angular/core';
 import { XHRBackend } from '@angular/http';
 import 'rxjs/Rx';
 import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

 import { InMemoryBackendService, SEED_DATA } from '../node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api';
 import { FavoriDataBase}               from './favori/favori-database';

 import { bootstrap }      from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
 import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';
 import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';

 bootstrap(AppComponent, [
HTTP_PROVIDERS, 
provide(XHRBackend, { useClass: InMemoryBackendService }),
provide(SEED_DATA,  { useClass: FavoriDataBase })]);
```

In systemjs.config.js I have this line `'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }`
And in package.json `"angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.10"`
I also updated `angular2-in-memory-web-api` in my console.

Everything worked find before I decide to use `'angular2-in-memory-web-api'`, I was using real http url to catch data and now I need to use "in folder url" to catch data of a created database (initially empty).

My database class:

```
export class FavoriDataBase {
createDb() {
let database= [];
return {database};
 }
}
```

Thanks by advance for any help !

Comment: Have you tried this? `import { InMemoryBackendService, SEED_DATA  } from 'angular2-in-memory-web-api';`

Comment: Yes, same problem...

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug. Here's the issue. https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api/issues/7

Answer (score 0):

I had to explicitly specify the providers:

```
providers: [
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    appRoutingProviders,
    { provide: XHRBackend, useClass: InMemoryBackendService },
    { provide: SEED_DATA, useClass: MyData }
  ],
```

where *MyData* is the class containing your fake data.

The description of the in-memory-api in the [quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#appendix-tour-of-heroes-in-memory-server) docs didn't mention this, but it worked for me.