# angular2-in-memory-web-api 404 error

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, angular-cli, angular2-http

I'm trying to build the 5 min app in angular 2 by this guide:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html.

In the http part, I added a fake server but I get 404 error because the angular2-in-memory-web-api.

```
http://localhost:4200/vendor/angular2-in-memory-web-api/in-memory-backend.service.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I was trying to follow this answer: [Angular2 Tutorial (Tour of Heroes): Cannot find module 'angular2-in-memory-web-api'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37377529/angular2-tutorial-tour-of-heroes-cannot-find-module-angular2-in-memory-web-a)

But he didn't use angular-cli + I don't have a clue where to add those dependencies they talked about there.

My main.ts:

```
// Imports for loading & configuring the in-memory web api
import { XHRBackend } from '@angular/http';

import { InMemoryBackendService, SEED_DATA } from 'angular2-in-memory-web-api';
import { InMemoryDataService }               from './app/in-memory-data.service';

// The usual bootstrapping imports
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent, environment } from './app/';
import { APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from './app/app.routes';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';
if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  { provide: XHRBackend, useClass: InMemoryBackendService }, // in-mem server
  { provide: SEED_DATA, useClass: InMemoryDataService }      // in-mem server data
]);
```

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "angular2-projects",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angupackage.lar/router": "3.0.0-beta.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "0.19.26",
    "zone.js": "0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.9",
    "codelyzer": "0.0.20",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "1.4.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "0.13.22",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "0.2.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "0.3.8",
    "protractor": "3.3.0",
    "ts-node": "0.5.5",
    "tslint": "3.11.0",
    "typescript": "1.8.10",
    "typings": "0.8.1"
  }
}
```

What do I need to do to make that error go away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to `npm i angular2-in-memory-web-api --save`

Then in
main.ts:

`import{InMemoryBackendService, SEED_DATA } from 'angular2-in-memory-web-api'`

in `src/system-config.js`:

```
const barrels: string[] = [
  // Angular specific barrels.
  '@angular/core',
  '@angular/common',
  '@angular/compiler',
  '@angular/forms',
  '@angular/http',
  '@angular/router',
  '@angular/platform-browser',
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',


  // Thirdparty barrels.
  'rxjs',
  'angular2-in-memory-web-api',

  // App specific barrels.
  'app',
  'app/shared',
  /** @cli-barrel */
];



    // Apply the CLI SystemJS configuration.
    System.config({
      map: {
        '@angular': 'vendor/@angular',
        'rxjs': 'vendor/rxjs',
        'main': 'main.js',
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'vendor/angular2-in-memory-web-api'
      },
```

and add this to `angular-cli-build.js` in your projects root directory:

```
   'angular2-in-memory-web-api/**/**/*.js'`
```

Finally restart the server and run `ng build` before `ng serve`.

Comment: Yes sorry, there was the error, I updated, and tested, no error for me now.

Comment: Just to make sure: I added to : dist/system-config.js and to src/system-config.ts. But I do get the same error: "http://localhost:4200/vendor/angular2-in-memory-web-api/in-memory-backend.service.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: ok, try restart the server and run `ng build` before `ng serve`

Comment: Works! Please add your last comment to the solution for rest of the people that will get this error. Thank you very much, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: do not add anything to `/dist`, that is the folder angular-cli adds everything.

Comment: js file does not have type so I cant add something like const barrels: string[]...

Answer (score 3):

Answering to an old post, however my solution was different so i thought i will post it here.

I was getting the exact same error mentioned using the latest package and using angular (4 and above).

The reason was in my `app.module.ts` i had imported the `InMemoryWebApiModule` prior to `HttpModule`. putting the `InMemoryWebApiModule` after `HttpModule` (and it should be like that undoubtedly) did the trick.

**Wrong**

```
imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      FormsModule,
      InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService),
      HttpModule,
      JsonpModule,
]
```

**Correct**

```
imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      FormsModule, 
      HttpModule,
      JsonpModule,
      InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService) //this has to be imported after httpModule
]
```

Comment: same issue and changing the import order fixed the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Adding answer for latest versions of angular2-in-memory-web-api since I've been hours trying to find 404 errors as well.

1)First of all angular2-in-memory-web-api is now deprecated for new [angular-in-memory-web-api](https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api), this means you need to make sure to change your package.json to have latest version:

```
"angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.6",
```

would need to change to something like:

```
"angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.1.3",
```

2)Remember to modify systemjs.config.js ([if in angular page tutorial for example as my case](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html)):

```
'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
```

3)In your module imports change to the latest version:

```
import { InMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api/in-memory-web-api.module';
```

needs to change to the new declaration:

```
import { InMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
```

4)Then rerun `npm install` and tha app should run with the latest version without any glitches. This solved the problem form me.

Comment: I like this. What threw me was the "angular2-in-memory-web-api" is *not* the latest. Following these instructions exactly fixed me up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you missed app.module configuration for in-memory web api, here is the section of the tutorial: [angular-toh-simulating-the-web-api](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html#!#simulating-the-web-api)