# Angular2 Tutorial (Tour of Heroes): Cannot find module './app-routing.module'

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-routing, angular-cli

I am going through the NG2 tutorial on [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html#!#register-for-http-services), but I've hit a stumbling block.

When I try and import my `AppRoutingModule` in my `app.module.ts` file I get a '`Cannot find module './app-routing.module`' error. I have seen this post on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37377529/angular2-tutorial-tour-of-heroes-cannot-find-module-angular2-in-memory-web-a), amongst other solutions, but they all seem to relate to `systemjs` and **not** `webpack`.

Here is my **package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "heroes",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.21",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.2.30",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.15",
    "codelyzer": "~0.0.26",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "4.0.5",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "3.13.0",
    "typescript": "2.0.2"
  }
}
```

Here is my **app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule }   from '@angular/router';

// Imports for loading & configuring the in-memory web api
import { InMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular2-in-memory-web-api';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module'; //ERROR
...


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeroDetailComponent,
    HeroesComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
  ],
   imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService), //ERROR: Cannot find name 'InMemoryDataServiceInMemoryDataService

    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'detail/:id', component: HeroDetailComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'heroes', component: HeroesComponent
      }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [HeroService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here is my specs (I am using angular CLI):

```
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.15
node: 4.2.6
os: linux x64 (ubuntu)
```

Not sure what else I can try? I guess I need to import the module somehow?

I did try and run:

```
npm install angular-route
```

But this led to:

```
├──UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY
@angular/common@2.0.0

├──UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY
@angular/core@2.0.0

├──UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY
@angular/platform-browser@2.0.0

└── angular-route@1.5.8
```

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Please add AppRoutingModule  code.

Comment: @SefaÜmitOray I don't seem to have AppRoutingModule  (not that I can see anyway), where should this file be?. I guess it's different to the `RouterModule.forRoot([...])` in my `app.module.ts`?

Comment: Previous tutorial shows how to create RoutingModule. Check it out. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout the [live](https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/toh-5/ts/plnkr.html) example with all the files

```
import { NgModule }             from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { DashboardComponent }   from './dashboard.component';
import { HeroesComponent }      from './heroes.component';
import { HeroDetailComponent }  from './hero-detail.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'dashboard',  component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: 'detail/:id', component: HeroDetailComponent },
  { path: 'heroes',     component: HeroesComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}


/*
Copyright 2016 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license
*/
```

Comment: Peter, is the link working? For me the plunker link shows the default 'Hello Plunker' page

Comment: Same here Peter, could you fix the link pls :)

Answer (score 0):

According to comments, it seems that you might be missing the app-routing file altogether. Perhaps you missed the piece describing that, or sometimes the documentation might be outdated. Please check the [plunker](https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/toh-6/ts/plnkr.html) showing a working, live example with the needed files.

Answer (score 0):

Right before making a new angular project, the CLI prompts you to either include routing or not, like this:

```js
Would you like to add Angular routing? Yes
```

Make sure you type in Y when it does so, or else your project won't be made with routing files.