# Tour of Heroes tutorial issue with "angular-in-memory-web-api"

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-tour-of-heroes

I am following Angular's [Tour of Heroes tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/). On the last part "HTTP", I get a blank page when adding "angular-in-memory-web-api". The terminal doesn't show any error message but I get this message on the browser's console:

```
localhost/:17 Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/traceur
    Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/traceur
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:698:29)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:265:35)
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:154:47)
        at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:335:33)
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/traceur
    Unable to load transpiler to transpile http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular-in-memory-web-api/index.js
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular-in-memory-web-api/index.js as "angular-in-memory-web-api" from http://localhost:3000/app/app.module.js
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:698:29)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:265:35)
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:154:47)
        at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:335:33)
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/traceur
    Unable to load transpiler to transpile http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular-in-memory-web-api/index.js
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular-in-memory-web-api/index.js as "angular-in-memory-web-api" from http://localhost:3000/app/app.module.js(anonymous function) @ localhost/:17
```

Here's my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w"
  },
  "licenses": [
    {
      "type": "MIT",
      "url": "https://github.com/angular/angular.io/blob/master/LICENSE"
    }
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~3.1.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~2.1.1",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.13",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.39",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.25"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.34",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.45",
    "concurrently": "^3.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.3"
  }
}
```

And here's my `systemjs.config.js`:

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',
      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api',
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': {
        main: './index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

I've looked at other SO questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37377529/angular2-tutorial-tour-of-heroes-cannot-find-module-angular2-in-memory-web-a), but they don't have the same issue and don't offer a solution for mine. Looks like they use older versions of the tutorial. It seems the "angular-in-memory-web-api" has been a bit troublesome for some time now.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `umd` bundle, as mentioned in the [`CHANGELOG`](https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)m and also remove it from the `packages`

> In `systemjs.config.js` you should change the mapping to:
>
> ```
> 'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'
> ```
>
> **then delete from `packages`:**
>
> ```
> 'angular-in-memory-web-api': {        
>    main: './index.js',     
>    defaultExtension: 'js'      
> }
> ```

**Note:** 0.1.14 should be avoided, as their is a [regression bug](https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api/issues/62). As of today, with 0.1.14 being the latest, use 0.1.13.